# One queue feeding multiple downstream blocks

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling a system in which units of raw materials are kept in large storage container. The raw materials are used in three different and unrelated manufacturing processes. Units of the raw material leave the storage container for any of these processes upon a request.

I was hoping to model the system as a queue block (the storage container) that is connected to three different delay blocks (manufacturing processes), i.e. three connections to the out port of the queue block. Between the queue block and the delay blocks would be a hold block that I can automatically block and unblock based on requests for raw material units. Please see attached image for the conceptual layout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ELB.jpg)

Unfortunately, it turns out that a queue block's out port can't be connected to multiple blocks.

Is there another way to solve this modeling problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No block can be connected to several downstream blocks, you have to manage that yourself using SelectOutput blocks.

However, in your case, I would use a `Wait` block and its `.free(MyRawMaterialAgent)` method which allows you to specify exactly which raw material agent to pull out.

(A queue block enforces a certain sequence, a wait block is a simple "throw in and forget" block for agents --> always read the help on the blocks you use to understand what they do )

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try the wait block and post an update.

Comment: Sure. If it was helpful, simply upvote the reply, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote